# Sparql: combine delete and describe

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

is it possible to delete all triples expressed by DESCRIBE in a single query?

Something like that:

```
DELETE { DESCRIBE <id:1> }
```

Comment: Given that `DESCRIBE` is not really specified (incoming edges, outgoing edges, both, bnodes resolved, etc.), the result of `DESCRIBE` depends on the triple store you use. You can at least just do it via a command like `DELETE WHERE {<id:1> ?p ?o}` - it depends on which triples you want to delete though

Comment: I currently use GraphDB, which resolves both edges and blank nodes.
So there is no shortcut for that kind of query?